# Unable to convert pandas dataframe column to int variable type using .astype(int) method

Tags: python, pandas, types, type-conversion, integer

I'm iterating through rows of a dataframe to extract values as follows but what I receive is always a float value and I'm not able to convert to int for both `result["YEAR_TORONTO"]` and `result["YEAR_TORONTO2"]`

```
for i in range(0, len(result)):
    if result["SOURCE_DATASET"].iloc[i] == "toronto":
        result["YEAR_TORONTO"].iloc[i] = pd.to_datetime(result["START_DATE"].iloc[i]).year
        result["YEAR_TORONTO"].iloc[i].astype(int) if not np.isnan(result["YEAR_TORONTO"].iloc[i]) else np.nan
        result["YEAR_TORONTO2"].iloc[i] = result["YEAR_TORONTO"].iloc[i]
```

Any idea as for why this could be? Tried multiple approaches including `pd.to_numeric` and `round()` but no luck despite the method

Interestingly enough, when I output
`result["YEAR_TORONTO"].iloc[1].astype(int) if not np.isnan(result["YEAR_TORONTO"].iloc[i]) else np.nan`,
I get `2016` as an int, but once I output the entire dataframe by calling `result`, I still get `2016.0` as a float

Sample Data (Input):

```
    SOURCE_DATASET  START_DATE
0   brampton        06-04-16
1   toronto         06-04-16
2   brampton        06-04-16
3   toronto         06-04-99
```

Sample Data (Output):

```
    SOURCE_DATASET  START_DATE  YEAR_TORONTO    YEAR_TORONTO2
0   brampton        06-04-16    NaN             NaN 
1   toronto         06-04-16    2016.0          2016.0  
2   brampton        06-04-16    NaN             NaN 
3   toronto         06-04-99    1999.0          1999.0
```

Just tried with `np.where` as well and getting the same result.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? And, hopefully this is not a big dataset since you are applying these operations element-wise, instead of by series.

Comment: Just added some sample data. Is there a problem with me doing this element wise? The records I'll get should only have 4 rows max but what would the problem be if there was more data?

Comment: There are NaNs, so be default all values are floats, for integers with `NaN`s need `result["YEAR_TORONTO"] = result["YEAR_TORONTO"].astype('Int64')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to use `astype()` is right but it does work if you column contain `nan`.  You could try to first split

```
result["YEAR_TORONTO"].astype(str).str.split('.', expand=True)[0].tolist()
```

And then separate then take it from there.

Alternatively

```
Result.loc[RESULT['TORONTO'].notnull(), 'x'] = result.loc[result['TORONTO'].notnull(), 'x'].apply(int)
```

Comment: Just tried including the first line of code and still getting a float with the same output as before. How does the second line work? I keep getting an error for the ```'x'```