# how to find out in a pandas DF column which values can not be converted to 'int' type with astype function

Tags: pandas, types

I am working with a dataframe and I have to convert a column into int type

i use the following notation:

```
result_df['ftmSectionId'] = result_df['ftmSectionId'].astype('int')
```

The DF has several million rows, so apparently there are some values that can not be converted into int (perhaps including commas or periods...) I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'not'
```

Now according to this question:
[How do I fix invalid literal for int() with base 10 error in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858595/how-do-i-fix-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-error-in-pandas)

I could use:

```
data.Population1 = pd.to_numeric(data.Population1, errors="coerce")
```

Which works.

But in this way I dont know why in the first place I got an error.
Due to the nature of the DataBase I am working with I would expect that particular column to have only Integers.
How could I query the column to find out which values can not be convert to 'int' with the simple approach .astype('int') ?

Thanks

Other possible answers but not duplicates:
[Unable to convert pandas dataframe column to int variable type using .astype(int) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031869/unable-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-column-to-int-variable-type-using-astypeint)
This question addresses the same problem, only that they know that the problem is that the column contains NaN and they remove them. I dont know what is the problem here, my goal here is not only convert to 'int' but rather catch the trouble values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an additional alternative:

```
def check_float(value):
try:
    float(value)
    return np.NaN
except ValueError:
    return value
```

We can call the function: [enter link description here](https://drawingfromdata.com/pandas/dtypes/finding-invalid-values-in-numerical-columns.html)

```
test = pd.Series([42, 3.1415, 'banana'])
test.apply(check_float)

0       NaN
1       NaN
2    banana
dtype: object
```

But I am not sure if it is scalable.

Here is a post discussing this issue [Finding invalid values in numerical columns](https://drawingfromdata.com/pandas/dtypes/finding-invalid-values-in-numerical-columns.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `errors="coerce"` and then get the values where it is `NaN` in the original series:

```py
s = pd.Series(["apple", "1.0", "2", -3, "pear", "12,84"])

nans = pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce").isna()
```

Then boolean indexing gives:

```py
>>> s[nans]

0    apple
4     pear
5    12,84
dtype: object
```